# How to make rows prior to decrease all $0 in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data:

| client_id | balance_month | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | $400 |
| 100000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | -$100 |
| 100000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $400 |
| 100000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $300 |
| 200000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | -$500 |
| 200000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | $100 |
| 200000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $100 |
| 200000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $100 |

What is the most efficient way to make all prior months prior to a month with a negative balance have $0 such that:

| client_id | balance_month | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | $400 |
| 100000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | -$100 |
| 100000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |
| 100000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |
| 200000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | -$500 |
| 200000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |
| 200000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |
| 200000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |

There could be months further back in history beyond June 2021, so I need to avoid having to have case statements for each prior row number (needs to be automated).

Comment: Why September 1 is non-zero?

Comment: Are you actually storing dates as `Month_name 1,year 12:00 AM`, and is the `$` actually part of the amount. If so the first thing is to fix your data model. Thost should be data types `date` and `numeric`.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear on what to do if a client has multiple negative balances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . As a query, you want to set the values to zero for all rows before the most recent negative balane.  One method is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when balance_month < max(balance_month) filter (where balance < 0) over (partition by client_id)
             then 0 else balance
        end) as new_balance
from t;
```

As an update:

```
update t
    set balance = 0
    where balance_month < (select max(t2.balance_month)
                           from t t2
                           where t2.client_id = t.client_id and
                                 t2.balance < 0
                          );
```